# How to execute Python script through php under Windows10

Tags: php, python

I have spent a lot of time looking for how I can actually run python script in php but for some reason it does not work.
I have got a login page and once you press button "Login", it should direct you to the next php page, which has to execute my python script.

Python:

```
#!c:/Python36/python.exe
import csv
import cgi, cgitb
import sys


data = {i[0]:i[1:] for i in csv.reader(open('students.csv'))}

Name = input("Please provide your name: ")
Subject = input("Please provide your Subject: ")

if Subject in data[Name]:
   print("you are registered")
else:
    print("you are not registered")
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
$result = shell_exec('Studmatch.py');
echo "$result";
?>
```

I am using free web hosting from webfreehosting.net

Thank you.

Comment: Not every web hosts supports the running of python scripts, nor has python installed

Answer (score 2):

You need `shell_exec('python Studmatch.py')`
You might need the full python path if it's not in your regular PATH environment variable.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it already but it does not execute my script properly... it runs the script but I can't enter any information because it is not active..

Comment: I checked and it runs just fine.
I think what you mean is it doesn't show output on the screen that's because it goes to a buffer that will be returned to shell_exec

Comment: Exactly, there is no output...but is it possible to make it work as it works through command line for example? I've never done this before so just trying different techniques